# Forms Authentication and Web Form

Tags: webforms, web-config, forms-authentication

I have a directory and I want to allow users which are only logged into. Also there is a web page in root directory which has several data and all visitors can see them. Web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".Artucltd" loginUrl="loginpage.aspx"
        protection="All" path="the_path" timeout="30" 
        cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users ="?" />
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This is custom login which controls username and password from MSSQL 2008 database. Everything works fine but I have a problem which is:

When I want to open default web page (http://localhost/test), system is automatically redirect to loginpage.aspx (not to Default.aspx). But I want to see Default.aspx and navigate to other pages. Loginpage.aspx is in root folder which is not protected and I want to do it same. In protected folder, there is another Default.aspx page and other protected pages. How can I get rid of this redirection? Should I specify this protected folder as application and put another Web.config file?

Processes that I tried up-to-now:

- Changed name of Default.aspx page in protected folder
- in IIS, default page is Default.aspx
- in Visual Studio 2010, I set default page as Default.aspx in root folder.

But no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found solution: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871